# What would be the most efficient or useful way to store attendance data?

Tags: python

I want to move my schools attendance records away from excel sheets and into python, but I'm not sure what the best way to store that data would be.

**Method 1**
Create a dictionary with student names as keys, and the dates they attended as items in a list. Or perhaps a list of the days they were absent would be more efficient.

```
attendance = {}
attendance["student_1"] = [2018-08-10, 2018-08-15, 2018-08-20]
```

**Method 2**
Create a dictionary of dates and append a list of students who were present on that day:

```
attendance = {}
attendance["2018-08-10"] = [student_1, student_2, student_3]
```

**Method 3**
Created nested dictionaries. Students names as the outer keys. All dates as inner keys with a boolean as a value.

```
attendance = {}
attendance["student_1"]= {}
attendance["student_1"]["1018-08-10"] = 'True'
```

All of these would probably work, but there must be a better way of storing this data. Can anyone help?

I should add that I want to be able to access the student's attendance record from name and retrieve all the student names that were present given a particular date.

Comment: You should benchmark. It depends a big lot on how much data you have and how you use (i.e. access) it. Are you expecting gigabytes of them, and e.g. many thousands of students? Read more about [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)s. Read also some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Comment: Will you primarily need to access attendance data given a student? Use method 1. Will you primarily need to access attendance data given a day? Use method 2.

Comment: The student numbers would probably never be more than 100 active students at a given time. The dates would continue to be added as long as the school remains open. I would like to be able to access the students attendance from the name, but retrieve all the students names from a date. Here in lies the problem.

Comment: "I'm not sure what the best way to store that data would be" => actually, none of the example you posted are about __storing__ data (persist them between program executions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you've delved into OOP (object-oriented programming), but this approach may be useful if you need to store more than just attendance in the future. See my 'basic' example:

#### Setup objects

```
students = []

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.attendance = {}

def add_attendance(date, students, values):
    for student, val in zip(students, values):
        student.attendance[date] = val
```

#### Setup students

This part could be done by reading from a text file with student data, but I've simplified here for brevity.

```
students = [
    Student('Bob', 15),
    Student('Sam', 14)
    ]
```

#### Add a day and record attendance

Again, I've hard-coded the dates here, but this would obviously come from an external source; the `datetime` module may prove useful here.

```
current_date = '27-08-2018'

attendance_values = [
    True,    # for Student(Bob)
    False    # for Student(Sam)
    ]

add_attendance(current_date,
               students,
               attendance_values)
```

Now, I'll add a 2nd day (Hard-coded for demonstration):

```
current_date = '28-08-2018'
attendance_values = [True, True]
add_attendance(current_date, students, attendance_values)
```

#### Display information

I can easily display `all` information:

```
>>> print('\n'.join([str(s.attendance)
...                  for s in students]))
{'27-08-2018': True, '28-08-2018': True}
{'27-08-2018': False, '28-08-2018': True}
```

Or, in a more 'friendly' way, and with each student name:

```
>>> print('data for 27-08-2018:')
>>> for student in students:
...    print('{:>10}: {}'.format(student.name,
...                              student.attendance['27-08-2018']))

data for 27-08-2018:
       Bob: True
       Sam: False
```

#### Storing externally

Currently, all data will be lost on the program's termination, so a possible text file structure could be the following.

Students:

```
Bob      15
Sam      14   # more data fields in columns here
```

Attendance:

```
27-08-2018
Bob            True    # or anything else to signify they were present
Sam            False

28-08-2018
Bob            True
Sam            True
```

Now you could read each file line by line, splitting by whitespace for the 'students' file, but for the 'attendance' file, things will most certainly be more difficult. This all depends on what data you include in your attendance file: it could just be a date with True/False values or a fully formatted record.

Comment: Yes, I always use OOP when programming, but it hadn't occurred to me to use it for this. Good Idea. I will have a play around with it when I get home. I could also include the contact details etc as attributes of each instance of the class.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was aiming at. I like using OOP as opposed to (nested) dictionaries as the dot notation `student.name` is so much easier to type than `student['name']`.  That can get messy when dealing with something like `students['john']['grades']['english']`

Answer (score 2):

It Completely depends on your use case. Each method has got its own advantage.

**Method 1**

```
attendance = {}
attendance["student_1"] = [2018-08-10, 2018-08-15, 2018-08-20]
total_days_present_student_1 = len(attendance["student_1"])
```

You have the advantage of getting easily the no. of days a student was present

**Method 2**

```
attendance = {}
attendance["2018-08-10"] = [student_1, student_2, student_3]
total_student_present_on_2018_08_10 = len(attendance["2018-08-10"])
```

You have the advantage of getting the total no. of students present on a particular day

**Method 3**

```
attendance = {}
attendance["student_1"]= {}
attendance["student_1"]["1018-08-10"] = 'True'
```

Not really any special advantage which the other 2 methods are providing

Answer (score 1):

> I want to move my schools attendance records away from excel sheets and into python, but I'm not sure what the best way to store that data would be.

Actually, none of the example you posted are about **storing** data (persist them between program executions). Updates to your `attendance` dict during the program's execution will be lost when the process finishes, and I seriously doubt you want your program users to edit the python code to add or change data.

To make a long story short, this kind of programs want a SQL database - which not only takes care of persisting your data but also makes querying **much** easier.